# How to add custom claims to access token in IdentityServer4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4

I am using [IdentityServer4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/).

I want to add other custom claims to access token but I'm unable to do this. I have modified Quickstart5 and added ASP.NET Identity Core and the custom claims via ProfileService as suggested by Coemgen [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44795605/103264).

You can download my code here: [zip package][3]. (It is based on: [Quickstart5](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess) with ASP.NET Identity Core and added claims via ProfileService).

Issue: GetProfileDataAsync does not execute.

Comment: I'm rather perplexed by this question, 001. You're clearly a very experienced user of Stack Overflow, but you've put your code in a file locker rather than in the question, and thus it is - as you must know - off topic. Are you able to repair the question, so it is not put on hold?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You should implement your own `ProfileService`.
Have a look in this post which I followed when I implemented the same thing:

https://damienbod.com/2016/11/18/extending-identity-in-identityserver4-to-manage-users-in-asp-net-core/

Here is an example of my own implementation:

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        //>Processing
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("FullName", user.FullName),
        };

        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        //>Processing
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);
        
        context.IsActive = (user != null) && user.IsActive;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to configure the service in your Startup.cs (via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44822276/45311))

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

Comment: thanks for that, however, it still does not work! no claims are added!

Comment: Are you target the GetProfileDataAsync function in debug mode ?

Comment: I am viewing the claims on the "secure" page here https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/release/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess/src/MvcClient/Controllers/HomeController.cs

Comment: What happens when you target your API ? What are the claims ?

Comment: All claims passed on the secure page is the same claims passed by the api. And they do not include the claims i added above via "ProfileService"

Comment: Okay, but if you add a break point, did you target GetProfileDataAsync ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147806/discussion-between-coemgen-and-001).

Comment: On startup, it executes this "            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>(); //AddClaims" but it break point, does not execute GetProfileDataAsync method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147911/discussion-between-001-and-coemgen).

Comment: If that does not work you may try to delete cookies for that site or at least to log out from your application and IdentityServer

Comment: See the answer of 001 below to have something that works ;-)

Comment: I had a problem where it wasn't being added to the ServicesCollection.  I had to move the services.AddTransient above the AddIdentityServer.

Comment: if you are calling _userManager.GetUserAsync in Login method to raise UserLoginSuccessEvent then _userManager.GetUserAsync will called twice? hitting DB twice?

Comment: This doesn't work for client_credentials

Comment: it is beyond me how information like this dont exist in the acutal documentation. thanks!

Comment: adding claims directly to `IssuedClaims` is not recommended. the recommended way is to use method `context.AddRequestedClaims` [link](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/quickstarts/5_aspnetid/#adding-custom-profile-data) to add only `requested claims`. and define `UserClaims` in `ApiScope` [link](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/fundamentals/resources/api_scopes/#adding-user-claims) to make those claims represent in `requested claims`.

Comment: I had to add  AddProfileService<ProfileService>() after  .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>() to make it work

Answer (score 58):

#### Ok the issue here is this:

although you have configured your **available** Identity resources correctly (both standard & custom), you also need to explicitly define **which ones are a necessity when calling your api** resource. In order to define this you must go to your `Config.cs` class on `ExampleIdentityServer` project and provide a third argument like on the `new ApiResouirce` constructor. Only those will be included into the `access_token`

```
// scopes define the API resources in your system
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API", new[] { JwtClaimTypes.Subject, JwtClaimTypes.Email, JwtClaimTypes.Phone, etc... })
    };
}
```

In essence this means that I got my identity claims configured for my organization but there may be more than one APIs involved and not all of the APIs make use of all available profile claims. This also means that these will be present inside your `ClaimsPrincipal` all the rest can still be accessed through the "userinfo" endpoint as a normal http call.

#### NOTE: regarding refresh tokens:

If you chose to enable refresh tokens via `AllowOfflineAccess = true`, you may experience the same behavior upon refreshing the access_token "**GetProfileDataAsync does not execute!**". So the claims inside the access_token stay the same although you get a new access_token with updated lifetime. If that is the case you can force them to always refresh from the Profile service by setting `UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh=true` on the client configuration.

Answer (score 47):

Issue found.

In startup.cs, instead of adding `services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();`, add `.AddProfileService<ProfileService>()` to `services.AddIdentityServer()`.

You will end up with

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

Thanks for Coemgen for helping out! Nothing wrong with the code, just the startup was wrong.

Comment: That's interresting. You also should be able to use services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>(); .

Comment: There is a great example on the Microsoft Architecture GitHub repository : https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/master/src/Services/Identity/Identity.API/Startup.cs

Comment: @Coemgen you can do that too! but you must add "            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();" after "services.AddIdentityServer()" :)

Comment: You can simply do this services.AddTransient<IdentityServer4.Services.IProfileService, CustomUserProfileService>(); and that will work

Comment: I believe that if you want to stick with `services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();` you should do that after adding identityserver to services so your registration will override that one made by IS

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: for anyone reading, order matters and the profileService should be registered last.

Answer (score 1):

You can include any claim by using UserClaims option in your GetIdentityResources() in the config class :

**UserClaims:**
List of associated user claim types that should be included in the identity token. (As per the official documentation) http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/identity_resource.html#refidentityresource

Comment: I tried that, it doesnt work!

Comment: I followed this, it does not work! http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/resources.html#defining-identity-resources